# How to partially clear userform in ms access

Tags: ms-access, userform

I have a bound userform with lot of fields in it, I use submit button to let user make entries in shared form. But whenever user clicks on submit button it requery whole form. However, there are around 4-5 fields which should not be cleared on submit button, they should retain the value and rest of the fields should get cleared on every submit button click.

Can this be done in access and how ? below is the simple code is use to submit and requery the record.

```
Private Sub SaveBtn_Click()
 RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
 Me.Requery
 Me.DataForm.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "shared form", and which form do the static fields reside in?

Comment: I mean the access file is in shared folder, multiple user uses the file. its a form "ManDC" in which I want to achieve the above said setup, I am sorry not sure what do you mean by static fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a "Bound Form" in Access, this means that the Access Form is tied to the underlying data source, which is specified by, and stored in, the "Record Source" property for the form.  In the "SaveBtn_Click()" method you provided above, this code does the following things:

1. RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord - Saves the current record in the form.
2. Me.Requery - Requeries the entire form.
3. Me.DataForm.Requery - Requeries the subform named "DataForm" on your main form.

So when you "Requery" the entire form (depending on how the "Record Source" and other form property settings are setup), the requery operation in some cases moves the cursor to the new record in the data source (...its the default settings for the drag and drop form designer tools in later versions of Access), and I suspect that is why you see the form being "cleared" when you call "Requery."  A couple of items I would point out, just for clarity:

Note 1: "Requery" actually saves the record, so explicitly calling "RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord" should not be necessary if you're going to call "Requery" too.

Note 2: Depending on how the Record Source (and other) form properties are set, Requery in some cases just saves and refreshes the currently selected record, but it doesn't sound like that is how your form is working (based on what you said above), so I'm assuming that is not the case in your form.

Note 3: The subform will also be requeried when you call "Requery" for the main form, so that line of code may also be redundant here.  The reason to call "Me.DataForm.Requery" is if you only want to requery the subform and NOT requery the entire main form.

Note 4: The "DataForm" subform (on your main form) will have a separate data source for it's own "Record Source" property, which is separate from the parent (main) form, so it is important to be aware of that fact, depending on which field values you want to save.

So, that said, there are a couple of options I might suggest, depending on exactly how you want your form to behave:

1. If you want to keep some of the field values and use those for the NEW RECORD when you hit the requery button, you could always save them off in a variable and then set those controls again after requerying from your variables. Just create a seperate variable for each value you want to save, copy the TextBox control values into each of variables respectively, call requery on the form, and then copy those values back into your TextBox controls after you requery.  That code would be something like the following (depending on the exact names of your TextBox controls, I used the fictitious name "txtMyTextBox" for this example):

   `Private Sub SaveBtn_Click()
       Dim vValue1 as Variant
       vValue1 = txtMyTextBox
       Me.Requery
       txtMyTextBox = vValue1
   End Sub`
2. Or, if you're just trying to create "Default Values" for certain controls, TextBox controls have a "DefaultValue" property you can set to any value you would like to use for the default.  Those can be set from the Property Sheet on the right side of the Access window when the form is opened in Design mode or Layout mode and the TextBox control is selected.  (Press F4 to open the Property Sheet if it's not already open).
3. But, if you really want to Requery and then go back to the same record you were previously on, you could try the following code:

   `Private Sub SaveBtn_Click()
       Dim iRecord as Integer
       iRecord = Me.CurrentRecord
       Me.Requery
       DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, iRecord
   End Sub`

Anyway, I hope this all makes sense and you find it helpful.  Please let me know if you have any further questions about this answer.

Comment: thank u so much this explained answer, yes i know the technique now, I think I should stiore the value in variables. the reson I used `Me.DataForm.Requery` is `Me.Requery` is not refreshing the subform for some reason. I will try to use the method 1 as if I use the 3rd option the form wil get all the values back and i just want the Value for few fields. Thanks for help